# build an includable template as string [django]

Tags: html, django, templates, django-templates, templatetags

I want to build a list of clickable links for my nav, and because these are links to my site, I want to use the url-tag. I get a list of dictonaries which knows all names for the links and create a template string with them with this function:

```
def get_includable_template(links):
  output = '<ul>'
  for link in links:
    output = output + '<li><a href="{% url' + get_as_link(link) + '%}>" + link['shown'] + '</a></li>'
  output = output + '</ul>
```

`links` looks like this:

```
links = [
  {'app': 'app1', 'view': 'index', 'shown': 'click here to move to the index'},
  {'app': 'app2', 'view': 'someview', 'shown': 'Click!'}
]
```

`get_as_link(link)` looks like this:

```
def get_as_link(link):
  return "'" + link['app'] + ':' + link['view'] + "'"
```

The first method will return a template, which looks like this (but it's all in the same code line):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="{% url 'app1:index' %}">click here to move to the index</a></li>'
  <li><a href="{% url 'app2:someview' %}">Click!</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want this to be interpreted as template and included to another template.

But how to include this?

Let's say, my other template looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block title %}App 1 | Home{% endblock %}
{% block nav %}INCLUDE THE TEMPLATE HERE{% endblock %}
{% block content %}...{% endblock %}
```

What I have already tried:

- make the template string a variable - doesn't work, because it doesn't interpret template language in variables (I couldn't find a template tag similar to `safe` which not only interprets HTML code but also template code.
- Building HTMl code in my methods (Isn't best-practice at all, because I needed to use absolute paths)

Is there a good solution about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Firstly, it seems that the only reason you need this to be interpreted as a template is so that it parses the `url` tag. But there is already a way of creating links in Python code, and that is the [`reverse()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse). You should use that instead.

Secondly, the way to dynamically generate content for use inside a template is to use a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/).